# Resolve promise in abstract parent before $stateChangeStart fires

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

I'm attempting to resolve some server-side data in an abstract parent state before the `Home` child state is loaded. I want to make sure I have the user's full name for examination in the state's `data.rule` function. However, using console.log statements, I can see the `userFullName` prints as an empty string to the console before the "done" statement in the `factory.privilegeData` method.

**EDIT**

The data in the parent resolve is security data from the server that needs to be available globally before any controllers are initialized. Only one child state is listed here (for the sake of readability), but all states, outside of `login` are children of the abstract parent. Once the parent's resolves are complete the data is stored in the `$rootScope` and used to determine access rights via the `data.rule` function in each state.

**config.js**

**UPDATE:** per answer below I've updated the parent/child states as such, howeve I'm still running into the same issue:

```
        .state('app', {
            url:'',
            abstract: true,
            template: '<div ui-view class="slide-animation"></div>',
            resolve:{
                privileges: ['$q', 'privilegesService', function($q, privilegesService){
                    console.log('from parent resolve');
                    return privilegesService.getPrivileges()
                                            .then(privilegesService.privilegesData)
                                            .catch(privilegesService.getPrivilegesError);
                }]
            }
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            parent: 'app',
            resolvePolicy: {when:'LAZY', async: 'WAIT'},
            authenticate: true,
            data:{
                rule: function($rootScope){
                    console.log("from home state data rule");
                    return true;
                }
            }                   
        })
```

**privilegesService.js**

```
factory.getPrivileges = function () {
    console.log('from server call');
    var queryString = "&cmd=privilege&action=user";
    return $http.get(config.serviceBaseUri + queryString);
};  

factory.privilegesData = function(priv){
    console.log('from privilege data');
    if(priv && priv.data) {
        $rootScope.userFullName = priv.data.firstName + ' ' + priv.data.lastName;
    }
        console.log('done');
};
```

Based on the `console` statments above I'm getting the following output. I need the `from home state data rule` to occur last...

[image]

...since I'm using the the results of the `data.rule` function for authorization for each state. Below is the `$stateChangeStart` from my `.run` method

**app.route.js**

```
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        if(toState.authenticate){
            if(authService.authKeyExists()){
                if(toState.data.rule($rootScope)){
                    navigationService.addNavObject("activity", {
                        summary : "Page navigation",
                        page : $location.absUrl().replace("#/", "")
                    });
                } else {
                    $state.go('app.home');
                }
            } else {
                event.preventDefault();
                $state.go('login');
            }   
        }
    });
```

Comment: You can use resolve directly in your child state and avoid this altogether

Comment: @ZeRubeus there are multiple child states that use the privilege data from the resolve. I've only included one for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1):

The child states need the parent state as a dependency in order for it to wait to load, even if its not used directly. [Source](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1903)

you have to try something like the following instead :

```
.state('app.home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/home/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    parent: 'app',
    authenticate: true,
    data:{
        rule: function($rootScope){
            console.log($rootScope.userFullName);
            return true;
        }
    }                   
})
```

You can use the property **[resolvepolicy](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/interfaces/state.statedeclaration.html#resolvepolicy)** and set it to LAZY as well, a state's LAZY resolves will wait for the parent state's resolves to finish before beginning to load.

Comment: Do you need to specify the dot notation in the state name as well as the `parent` property (in the child states)? I currently have the `parent` set to `app`

Comment: Also (I'll add an edit to clarify this in my post), the data i need resolved in the parent is global data used by the rest of the site. I actually don't need to inject it into any of the child states, its server data that's stored in the `$rootScope`.

Comment: remove the parent and use the dot notation, or simply use the resolvepolicy: 'LAZY'

Comment: Do I need to define a `resolve` property in the child state as well or simply `resolvePolicy` since it's parent contains a `resolve`?

Comment: yes this way : `resolvePolicy: { when: 'LAZY', async: 'WAIT' },`

Comment: Gotcha.. not sure what the `resolve` value would in this case. Would it simply be be `appResolves` or do I need to specify each value in the parent `resolve`? If not any chance you could include in your answer?

Comment: Sorry was following a naming convention in one of the links you sent. I'm not sure what I should set the `resolve` property in the `home` state to? The data being gathered in the parent state's `resolve` will be available in the `$rootScope`, it doesn't need to be injected into the `home` controller.

Comment: I updated my post so you can see my most recent attempt. I added the `resolvePolicy` and included the dot notation in the state name but still getting the same result. Not sure what I need to set the `resolve` to.